# How to configure Gradle TestNGOptions in a custom plugin written in Java?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I'm writing a custom Gradle plugin that will create a new Test task and run it. I need to set some configuration on this test task.

The plugin is written in Java and the code to execute the Test task looks like this:

```
private void runSmokeTests() {

    Test test = new Test();
    test.useTestNG(new Closure(/* What goes in here? */) {
        // and here? How do I get hold of TestNGOptions?
    });

    test.executeTests();

}
```

I can't figure out how to use the Closure class from Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest option is just to call `getOptions()` and cast to the appropriate type.

```
test.useTestNG();
TestNGOptions options = (TestNGOptions) test.getOptions();
// configure options ie...
options.setPreserveOrder(true);
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Mark.